# JBAS018062: 'sessionModelDataMB' attribute with type 'au.com.test.SessionModelData' cannot be replicated

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I'm running JBoss EAP 6.1.0 with a spring hibernate and JSF application.

The project starts up fine, but when I try to access any page on the project it throws a "attribute with type [xyz] cannot be replicated" error. Trace at the bottom of this post. 
The [xyz] class is a JSF @ManagedBean with @SessionScoped.
It is wired to two other @ViewScoped @ManagedBeans using the @ManagedProperty("#{xyz}") annotation.

I searched the web only to find related ones:

- https://community.jboss.org/thread/229699
- https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-5800

which seem to suggest it is something do to with serialization. But since the source already works on another machine and I'm simply setting it up on my, I think it might be more of a Jboss configuration issue.

Any ideas what can cause this and possible fixes?

```
ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/testapp].[default]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS018062: 'sessionModelDataMB' attribute with type 'com.test.SessionModelData' cannot be replicated
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSession.setAttribute(ClusteredSession.java:808) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade.setAttribute(StandardSessionFacade.java:130) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:141) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:61) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager$SessionScopeHandler.handle(BeanManager.java:578) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager.pushToScope(BeanManager.java:457) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder$Expression.evaluate(BeanBuilder.java:591) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder$BakedBeanProperty.set(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:606) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanBuilder.buildBean(ManagedBeanBuilder.java:133) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:104) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:408) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:268) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:94) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:239) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.DeclarativeSystemEventListener.processEvent(EventHandler.java:128) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent$ComponentSystemEventListenerAdapter.processEvent(UIComponent.java:2486) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:106) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2161) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeComponentListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2109) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:289) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:247) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:107) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139) [jsf-impl-2.1.19-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19-redhat-1]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.19.1.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79) [primefaces-3.5.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:145) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:832) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:620) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:553) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:482) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:137) [prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.3.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at au.test.filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:64) [classes:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:246) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.handleRequest(ClusteredSessionValve.java:134) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.ClusteredSessionValve.invoke(ClusteredSessionValve.java:99) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.JvmRouteValve.invoke(JvmRouteValve.java:92) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.session.LockingValve.invoke(LockingValve.java:64) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

Comment: and does `com.test.SessionModelData` implement serializable?

Comment: It worked, left puzzled as to why the application worked with out the Serializable JSF Managed Bean on someone else's computer but not mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I set the [xyz] and all other JSF Managed Bean and their contained variables to Serializable.

The error went away.

I'm left puzzled as to why the application worked with out the Serializable JSF Managed Bean on someone else's computer but not mine.

After further research, I found my JBoss EAP 6.1 has been configured for Infinispan (http://infinispan.org/), and it was caching the session objects. Because these objects were not Serializable, it couldn't store them and hence throwing the error.

With the old cold, the errors went away as soon as I removed the Inifispan configuration in jboss.